# Mod_rewrite last part of url only

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum/topic/1234
```

I need to rewrite this to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum/topic/1234-this-is-a-test
```

Here is what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)$ topic/$1-this-is-a-test [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, just add R flag:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)/?$ topic/$1-this-is-a-test [L,R]
```

Comment: Ok so I have:

RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)/?$ topic/$1-this-is-a-test [L,R]

Still not working..

Comment: What URL are you trying for testing?

Comment: http://www.mysite.com/forum/topic/1234  Needs to redirect to:

http://www.mysite.com/forum/topic/1234-this-is-a-test  Of course 1234 could be 3456 or any series of numbers.